# How to remove javax annotation warnings

Tags: java, annotations, javax

How can I remove the following warnings ?

```
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: javax.annotation.Generated
warning: No processor claimed any of these annotations: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements,
                                                        javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID,javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement,javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef,
```

Comment: Where are you getting this warning in IDE or during build?

Comment: Considering that this warning occurs during your build process, you could set your log level to Error.

Comment: @Bhavesh during my build using ant

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have these annotations (`@Generated`, `XmlElements`, `XmlID`) somewhere in the code you are compiling or running.

If no processor claimed the annotations, it could mean a big trouble for you, if you rely on the annotations to have any effect, and that is why the warnings are there.

Disabling warnings is usually possible, but I don't think it's a good idea. You would pretty much only hide symptoms, but the problem is there. Then someone else has to fix this problem and wastes a day trying to find out where is the smell coming from, because the shit is hidden under a nice carpet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same warning for `@javax.annotation.Generated`, but only during a clean build. The second time I build, the warning for `@javax.annotation.Generated` not being claimed goes away. I don't fully understand why that is but since it's only a warning on the first build, I just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for information ! didn't find solution yet, I just ignored them as you did